# How to find out which key Meta is bound to in a Windows virtual desktop accessed from a Mac?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am trying to configure GNU Emacs 26.3 which runs in the following setup:

1. There is the Macbook.
2. From this Macbook I connect to a virtual desktop which runs under Windows 10.
3. Emacs runs inside this virtual machine.

**How can I figure out which keyboard key corresponds to the Meta key?**

Here is what I tried out (the desired result in all cases is to see `M-x` in the minibuffer):

1. Press the left Command key and x. Result: `C-x-` is displayed in the minibuffer.
2. Press the left Option key and x. Result: `» is undefined` is displayed in the minibuffer.
3. Press the right Option key and x. Result: `» is undefined` is displayed in the minibuffer.
4. Inside Emacs, press the right Command key and x. Result: A Windows menu with items like `Apps and Features`, `Power Options`, `Event Viewer` etc. is displayed.

**Update 1**

When I write

```
(message "w32-alt-is-meta is set to: %s" w32-alt-is-meta)
```

in the scratch buffer and execute the script via the menu it produces the following output.

```
"w32-alt-is-meta is set to: t"
```

**Update 2**

When I launch Emacs using `runemacs.exe -Q`, then `ESC-x` leads to `M-x` being displayed in the minibuffer.

But when I launch Emacs in the normal mode (without `-Q`), then (I assume) the following `~/.emacs` file is being used in which evil mode is enabled. In this case, `ESC-x` does not work as `M-x` because the Escape key is being used by the evil mode.

**.emacs**

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (evil))))
(custom-set-faces)
(setq w32-alt-is-meta nil)
```

Comment: Ensure that you are starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`.  Have your tried `ESC x`?

Comment: I believe `C-[` will also generate `ESC`.  Once you get ESC or `M-` key working, Start Emacs with `emacs -q --eval "(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'view-lossage)"`, randomly press  some keys, and one of the windows will tell what keys Emacs sees and what commands they map to.  (You can see what effect this invocation of Emacs does at [the beginning of this video](https://github.com/rnchzn/scratch/issues/1).

Comment: @mxnt See update 2. When launched with `emacs -Q`, then `ESC-x` indeed works. Looks like the problem is evil mode.

Comment: When I press `C-[` I see `[-` in the minibuffer.